# How do I update data inside documents without specifying the document ID?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to  update data inside documents without specifying the document ID,

But while going thorugh stackoverflow I saw this code

```dart
firebase.firestore().collection("users")
  .where("name", "==", "Daniel")
  .get(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(document) {
     document.ref.update({ ... }); 
    });
  });
```

Can someone please translate this to flutter code(Dart) please. It's a query to norrow down the document search without having to put in the document ID. I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dart equivalent to code you posted would look like this:

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('users')
  .where('name', isEqualTo: 'Daniel')
  .getDocuments()
  .then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.documents.forEach((documentSnapshot) {
      documentSnapshot.reference.updateData({ ... });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you help me, how to handle insert scenario along with this? Like if exists then update, else insert?

Comment: @ManuGupta You can use `setData` with `merge: true`.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Thanks, will it take care of both update and insert in one go?

Comment: @ManuGupta Yes, see [the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/setData.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the Id by:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users')
  .where('name', isEqualTo: 'Daniel')
  .getDocuments()
  .then((querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.documents.forEach((documentSnapshot) {
String uniqueID = documentSnapshot.id;
//now you can do whatever you wanted with that id
    });
  });
```